# ASP.NET Core 6 uses default identity pages instead existing ones

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a .NET Core 5 web application with customized login and register pages, recently I updated the framework to .NET 6 and did no changes in code. It loads it's default Identity pages instead of existing ones. I don't want to load default identity pages and I want to use my existing pages. what's the problem.
Here is my current rout in Startup.cs

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Admin", "/");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("User", "/");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/account/register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Id", "/account/register");
});
```

Comment: You can try to change the anchor link in _LoginPartial.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right click anywhere in "Solution Explorer", then "Add>New Scaffolded Item", in the pop-up menu select "Identity", it will show a dialog with checkboxes, check the views you want to override (e.g. Account\Login, Account\Register), and select your data context class, then click [Add].

The views you've selected will be added to your solution under Areas\Identity\Pages... (e.g. Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml), you may now override it with the old view you have.

see [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2116645.)